# Word for change of opinion

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for “changing one’s opinion”?

I’m looking for something similar to *concede*, but that implies that the person knew the right answer all along but was just pretending that the answer was something else. What if I want to imply that the person was sure of something, but something changed what he thought?

More specifically, the sentence I’m writing is

> He thought this . . . but after being criticized, he __ that the critics were correct".

It’s actually a negative effect, his way of thinking permanently changed due to criticism (and I’m trying to say his original opinion was better).

Comment: Is this a simple reversal of their opinion?
Or more along the lines that they'd been convinced based on facts or arguements presented?

Comment: This is Not Constructive. If he knew all along, he *conceded, admitted*, and if he didn't, he *accepted, realised*. If his whole world-view was permanently changed by losing the argument, perhaps he had an [epiphany](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphany_(feeling))

Comment: It's an opinion. There's nothing to be known. It wasn't an argument, it as criticism. See the answer I accepted; that fits what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the final sentence of the question (as quoted below) related words among others include *[co-opt](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/co-opt#English)*,
*[assimilate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/assimilate)*, *[hoodwink](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hoodwink)*, *[cave](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cave#Verb)*, and perhaps *[recant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/recant)*.

> It's actually a negative effect, his way of thinking permanently changed due to criticism (and I'm trying to say his original opinion was better).

However, to fit those words into your sample sentence (“he thought this ... but after being criticized, he __ that the critics were correct”) requires adjustments, perhaps as illustrated in the following samples.

> • He thought his views were sound but the critics soon co-opted him.
>   •  His views were sound, but he caved under withering criticism.
>   •  Under light but  unrelenting peer pressure, he recanted and was assimilated.
>   •  Despite his precise and marvelous mind, the critics soon hoodwinked him.

Comment: Wow! Recant is so amazingly perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: Some of these strongly imply weakness, corruption or deceit; *recant* has the advantage of neutrality.

Answer (score 2):

Not a word, but a phrase: "saw the light"

edit (after comment by OP)

***Submit (to)***, then, or "***knuckle under***"

Comment: No, I'm not trying to imply that his new way of thinking was right. More specifically, the sentence I'm writing is "he thought this ... but after begin criticized, he _____ that the critics were correct". It's actually a negative effect, his way of thinking permanently changed due to criticism (and I'm trying to say his original opinion was better)

Comment: I searched for synonyms of submit, and found 'succumbed', so I've used 'succumbed to believe', which I feel carries the right connotation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A few options come to mind:

> "he thought this... but after being criticized, he __ that the critics were correct"

- realized
- agreed
- concurred
- admitted
- was persuaded

Comment: +1, or decided, concluded, came around to the fact

Comment: I'm trying to emphasize that he changed his mind for the worse. Something like "I practiced music therapy. He was criticized harshly, and he was so affected by it that he even started giving speeches against it". So he ___ that the critics were correct.

Comment: Depending on the context, perhaps "convinced himself" might work as well. Although, that too carries with it a certain a connotation. Based upon the answer you accepted, I assume you're looking to imply an element of disguist or otherwise distastefulness. How about: "So he *relegated* himself into believing that his critics were correct."?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like: 
 gave in, 
 backed down, 
 capitulated, 
 caved in, 
 conceded, 
 resigned, 
 surrendered, 
 threw in the towel, 
 washed his hands of, 
 yielded

Comment: I'm not saying he gave into it. I'm saying he was completely converted (and I think for the worse). These words imply that he just gave up hope and agreed with his critics. But thanks for resigned, that helped me elsewhere :)

Comment: @asymptotically- Oh, I see, so he was corrupted, tainted, warped, perverted, or debauched?

Answer (score 0):

- *capitulated*
- *acquiesced*
- *agreed begrudgingly*
- *resigned himself to the fact*
- *caved in under pressure*

Answer (score 0):

He thought this . . . but after being criticized, he "**acquiesced**" *and agreed*  that the critics were correct.

"acquiesce to":  To yield or succumb to one's requests or demands.